# Подскажите хорошее решение для модального окна с подтверждением

Tags: jquery, json, php, javascript

Здравствуйте.
Нужно реализовать следующее:
Если переменная $hash имеет значение больше 1 - показывается модальное окно, в котором 2 кнопки Yes и No
Если пользователь жмет кнопку  Yes -   выполняется sql запрос и контент этого же окна меняется на текст - например "Запрос выполнен"

А если пользователь жмет кнопку  No -   выполняется другой sql запрос и контент этого же окна меняется на текст - например "Запрос отменен"

Comment: @RattleSneyk,  Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: У меня сейчас просто выполняется запрос в базу. 
Пользователь переходит по ссылке - в ссылке и есть $hash.
И выполняется запрос. 
Вот мне и нужно вместо запроса поставить всплытие модального окна - 1. 
2 - сделать действия по кнопка а модальном окне.

Comment: Ну второе я и сам могу сделать в принципе=)) 
Больше нужно всплытие этого окна.

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation
http://kylefox.ca/jquery-modal/examples/index.html

Comment: еще можно fancybox: http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/

Answer (score 2):

Если речь идёт о web, то вы задаёте вопрос, касающийся концептуальных основ клиент-серверных технологий. Если в алгоритме требуется выбор пользователя, то сделайте для этого диалог через пользовательский интерфейс, а затем добавьте поведение, зависящее от выбора пользователя.

Более точно ответить на ваш вопрос просто невозможно.

Единственное затруднение, выходящее за рамки обычного взаимодействия - это когда **полностью** серверной реализации какого-то алгоритма приспичило узнать мнение пользователя. В этом случае такие решения:

- спросить пользователя заранее, до того как начался процесс, пользуясь для этого возможностями диалогового интерфейса. Вспомните любой установщик софта - они сначала спрашивают, куда устанавливать, а потом устанавливают.
- хранить настройки по-умолчанию в конфиге. если спросить нельзя, то действовать как обычно
- экстренно завершить процесс. если решение оператора важно, а его получить нельзя, то остановить процесс, а лучше даже вернуть как было до начала процесса (откат изменений)

И ещё одна интересная задача: реализовать полностью серверное решение с диалогом. Обычно для PHP это только интерфейс командной строки, так что ни о каком модальном окне речь идти не может. А для чтения с устройства ввода по умолчанию (консоль, клавиатура), в PHP есть такое решение: http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

```
<?php
echo "Continue? [yes|no]";
$handle = fopen("php://stdin","r"); // читать клавиатуру
$line = fgets($handle); // читать строку (нужно ввести yes или no и нажать Enter)
if(strtolower(trim($line)) != 'yes') {
    echo "ABORTING!\n";
}
echo "\n";
echo "Continuing...\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно ведь просто вызвать окно javascript -

```
<script>
var choice = confirm("Yes or no?");
</script>
```

В зависимости от ответа изменить boolean-переменную, отвечающую за выбор пользователя, ну и дальше простым if-ом разобраться с посылкой запроса.

Если нужны просто всплывающие "псевдо-модальные окна", то в интернете полно решений как на jquery, так и на чистом js, вот например - arcticlab.ru/arcticmodal/#desc